# JavaScript Not Persisting On Page After Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a simple exercise where a user submits a form and the info in the form is displayed in some p tags. When I click the submit button, the user input flashes onto the screen briefly (in the p tags) before disappearing. How do I get what the user is typing in the input boxes to persist in the p tags after they submit the form?

Here is the HTML.

```
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Enter A Force User</h1>
    <form name="force-user-form" id="force-user-form">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="name" name="name" id="force-user-name">
      <label>Dark or Light</label>
      <input type="text" value="side" name="side" id="force-user-side">
      <input type="button" value="Enter Force User" id="force-user-submit" onclick="newForceUser()">
    </form>

    <p id="name-display" >*</p>
    <p id="side-display" >*</p>

    <script src="force-user-form.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript (the console.log is returning whatever value I type into the submit box)

```
"use strict";

var $ = function(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var newForceUser = function(){

  var forceUserName = $("force-user-name").value;
  var forceUserSide = $("force-user-side").value;
  var isValid = true;

  $("name-display").firstChild.nodeValue = forceUserName;
  $("side-display").firstChild.nodeValue = forceUserSide;

  $("force-user-form").submit()

  console.log(forceUserName);

};

window.onload = function(){
  $("force-user-submit").onclick = newForceUser;
  $("force-user-name").focus();
};
```

Comment: Use AJAX instead of form.sbumit();

Comment: localstorage might help.